# Java Error: Cannot convert from void to int[]

Tags: java

I don't understand why java thinks the array "thisRow" is void when it is passed into Arrays.sort(thisRow).  "thisRow" appears to be an int[] to me.  What is the issue here?

Error Message: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to int[] at Test.mySort(Test.java:57)"

```
private static int[][] mySort(int[][] anArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){
        int thisRow[] = getRow(anArray, i);
        int[] sorted = Arrays.sort(thisRow);
    }
}

//This method will get the specified row out of the array.
private static int[] getRow(int[][] anArray, int row) {
    int thisRow[] = new int[anArray[row].length];
    for(int j = 0; j < anArray[row].length; j++){
        thisRow[j] = anArray[row][j];
    }
    return thisRow;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) returns `void` not `int[]` type.

As per javadoc

> Sorts the specified array of ints into ascending numerical order. The
>   sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort, adapted from Jon L. Bentley
>   and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function",
>   Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November
>   1993). This algorithm offers n*log(n) performance on many data sets
>   that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance

Replace

```
int[] sorted = Arrays.sort(thisRow);
```

with

```
Arrays.sort(thisRow);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.sort` sorts the array in-place (by mutating the existing object), and doesn't return anything.  Hence you should replace

```
int[] sorted = Arrays.sort(thisRow);
```

with simply

```
Arrays.sort(thisRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays#sort` does not return `int[]`, it returns `void` , it sort source array itself.

> Sorts the specified array of ints into ascending numerical order. The
>   sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort, adapted from Jon L. Bentley
>   and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function",
>   Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November
>   1993). This algorithm offers n*log(n) performance on many data sets
>   that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance.