# Why can't I assign the output of Arrays.sort() in a array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have been learning java for a while now but im still a beginner, I am trying to write a snippet to sort an array in java by declaring an another array where its elements are the sorted elements of the first array. But it shows an error. What might be the cause?

```
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
       int[] arr = new int []{34,65,35,37,46,86};
       int res[];
       res=Arrays.sort(arr);
       for(int i: res)
       System.out.println(i+" ");
     }
}

Error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int[] 
       res=Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Comment: I tried the program without implementing a second array. It is like follows,
public static void main(String []args)
     {
       int[] arr = new int []{34,65,35,37,46,86};
       Arrays.sort(arr);
       for(int i: arr)
       System.out.println(i+" ");
     }
}
This snippet works just fine, I just need to know why the first one didnt work, Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of [Java Error: Cannot convert from void to int\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382619/java-error-cannot-convert-from-void-to-int)

Comment: Hi @YokeshwarB, since you are a beginner to java - a suggestion for you. Whenever you are using any method in java, check the return type of it before assigning. In the current scenario, return type of Arrays.sort is void(  which means it doesn't return anything) and you were trying to assign it to an integer array. Hence it was giving you an error. Hope it helps.. Enjoy coding. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Arrays.sort()` is a `void` function

```
public static void main(String []args)
     {
       int[] arr = new int []{34,65,35,37,46,86};
       Arrays.sort(arr);
       for(int i: arr ) {
        System.out.println(i+" ");
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`Arrays.sort(arr)` has a return type of void (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/), you cannot assign it to `res` of type `int[]`. Instead, it modifies the array that has been passed to the function.

So just call `Arrays.sort(arr)` by itself, and your `arr` array will be sorted.

Comment: In addition, If you want to have both an unordered and an ordered array, you can make a copy of the first one first using `int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length)`, and then ordering `copy` using `Arrays.sort(copy)`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort has **no** return value. It sorts the contents parameter array (your arr variable) by changing their order *in the original array*. Meaning: you don't have to re-assign the array, just call Arrays.sort(arr) and the next time you use arr you'll find that the elements are sorted.